# Ignore/replace element attributes in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I have been searching without any results, does anyone here know how to **ignore** and/or **replace** element attributes in TinyMCE?

For example:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tdTable" style="margin: 0 20px 0 0;">
```

I would like to replace the code above to:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5">
```

Answer (score 3):

tinyMCE brings this functionality within its dom.parser:

```
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.Serializer.addAttributeFilter('class,style', function(nodes, name) {
        for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            console.log(nodes[i].name);
            tinyMCE.dom.setAttrib(nodes[i], 'class', null);
            tinyMCE.dom.setAttrib(nodes[i], 'style', null);
            // Process the nodes here (e.g. set attribute to null or delete Attribute)
        }
    });
```

You can also apply the change for the whole array:

```
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.Serializer.addAttributeFilter('class', function(nodes, name) {
        tinyMCE.dom.setAttrib(nodes, 'class', null);
    });
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.Serializer.addAttributeFilter('style', function(nodes, name) {
        tinyMCE.dom.setAttrib(nodes, 'style', null);
    });
```

See here for a complete documentation of the functions: 
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:namespace.tinymce.dom

Comment: +1 good answer - some more knowledge concerinign tinymce i didn't know

Comment: you are welcome. I usually don't work much with tinyMCE, but this is a must know when letting publishers edit content for a CMS page with it...

Answer (score 1):

use the invalid_elements setting when initializing the editor
for example, i use:

```
invalid_elements: '@[onclick|ondblclick|onmousedown|onmouseup|onmouseover|onmousemove|onmouseout|onkeypress|onkeydown|onkeyup],script,input,select,option,button,textarea,form',
```

to get rid of all the mentioned elements/attributes at the output text

Comment: doesn't this remove the complete element? btw the doc says that you can not use attributes in the list: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:invalid_elements

Comment: i had the valid_element setting in mind - not the invalid element setting. and yes the whole element gets removed